# Is it possible to create a new folder in Android Studio to use images without encountering 'Unresolved reference' errors?

Tags: android, kotlin

Unresolved reference: father_and_son_2258681
I imported R folder and while i click on the image, android studio sees all images, however when i click run, i get 30 errors "Unresolved reference". Images were imported and are in folder drawable-thx. If I move them to drawable they it all compiles flawlessly, but only there mipmap-xxhdpi and etc. doesn't work as well. Can create own folder in res and use the images from there?

Project look and errors:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid directory name for drawable resources. It needs to be `drawable`, or (more commonly) `drawable` followed by valid resource set qualifiers. `-thx` is not a valid resource set qualifier, so `drawable-thx` is not going to be recognized by the build system.

Comment: What are the valid set qualifiers? I mean for the sake of argument I create huge app with 1000 images how to put them in the folders?

Comment: @Mioshek: Resource directory names are for telling Android the rules of when to use the resources. Resource directory names are not for organization. So, you would have 1000 images in a directory, most likely. You can read about the role of resource set qualifiers in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources?hl=en#QualifierRules). FWIW, I also cover the topic in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/).